# Is it correct to say "I fell off my bike while riding with my friends"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, expressions

What I want to say is:

1. I fell off my bike.
2. I was riding a bike with my friends.

=> I fell off my bike while riding with my friends.
or
=> I fell while riding a bike with my friends.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 3):

Both are correct and mean the same. Both mean

> I fell off my bike while riding a bike with my friends.

with the redundant information removed.  In terms of style, I would choose

> I fell off my bike while riding with my friends.

As it doesn't require backtracking.  "I fell while riding a bike with my friends." requires the listener to use the information in the second part of the sentence as a context for the first, and this causes slight difficulty.

Answer (score -1):

“Riding a bike with my friends” would imply *one* bike. No wonder you fell. Use “riding the bike”. Just “riding” if you were riding a horse if that is clear from the context.

“I fell” on its own is not very clear. For example you might have got off your bike to climb some steps and fallen at that time. For all these reasons I’d say “I fell off my bike while riding with my friends”, that’s the clearest.